# How to store number set in nestjs + typeorm

Tags: set, nestjs, typeorm

I am making a project using nestjs and typeorm.

But I don't know how to apply the set type.

I'm writing a question because there are too many meanings of `set` and it's hard to find.

```js
  @IsNumber()
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Min(0)
  @Max(300)
  data: number;
```

Previously, only one value was entered as above.

But now multiple values ​​must be input.

```js
  @IsNumber()
  @Column({ type:'set', nullable: true })
  @Min(1)
  @Max(15)
  data: number[];
```

If I write the code as above and sync the `typeorm`,
an error occurs and it does not run.

Please tell me how to set the `set` type by setting min and max values ​​for each.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do this following code:

```
  @IsNumber({ each: true })
  @Column("simple-json", { nullable: true })
  @Min(1, {each: true})
  @Max(15, {each: true})
  data: number[];
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't write that I use `mysql`. Execution fails with an error  `Data type "Array" in "TableName.data" is not supported by "mysql" database.`

Comment: I've changed the type to simple-json, because as you said before array:true is not supported for MySQL, maybe you can try this changes

Comment: Is there any difference between using `simple-json` and using it as a `string`? With json, wouldn't the search have to go through a conversion process?

Comment: when you use simple-json, the array automatically converted as string when it stored to database (via JSON.stringfy()) but when you want to get the data, typorm automatically convert the string to array again (via JSON.parse()), for reference you can see this link https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entities#simple-json-column-type

Comment: thank you for your reply! I will study through the link!